# Angular acumula un proceso al navegar entre los distintos componentes de mi aplicación

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo la siguiente función en un javascript externo para cambiar un poco la apariencia (colores) de mi menú estático, dependiendo de en que sección de mi página me encuentre. Esta función importo en cada uno de mis componentes donde quiero modificar dicha apariencia del menú.

```
floatMenu = (bg, color) => {
  let lastScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    const currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    if (currentScroll > lastScroll) {
      // scroll down
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) {
        $('.custom-navbar')
          .addClass('top-nav-float')
          .css('background-color', bg);
        $('.nav li a').css('color', color);
      }
    } else {
      // scroll up
      if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $('.custom-navbar')
          .removeClass('top-nav-float')
          .css('background-color', '');
        $('.nav li a').css('color', '');
      }
    }
    lastScroll = currentScroll <= 0 ? 0 : currentScroll;
  });
};
```

Por ejemplo, en un componente home correspondiente a la sección Home, lo importo así.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

declare const floatMenu: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    floatMenu('', '#0B0C0B');
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

En mi pagina tengo diferentes secciones como Contacto, Perfil, etc, en las cuales llamo de igual forma a esta función. Me di cuenta que mientras navegaba entre estas secciones, el proceso para modificar la apariencia se iba acumulando por decirlo así. Haciendo un console.log, obtuve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso estoy detectando cuando se hace scroll por la página, para lo cual ya habia navegado 6 veces en total en mi pagina, obteniendo así, 6 veces por cada scroll o posición. Esto obviamente afecta el rendimiento y el comportamiento de la página. ¿Porque obtengo este comportamiento, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: En cada sección tienes ese mismo código y te sale 6 veces... tal vez tengas ese código puesto 6 veces?? Si en ese código lees el scroll de la página entera lo suyo sería tenerlo puesto solo una vez, porque si no, pasa eso

Comment: Mmm no, llamo a ese código js en cada componente, se va acumulando según navegue por la página, por ejemplo: Cuándo recién cargo la página (Home), todo va bien, si navego hacia la página Contacto, el código se acumula 1 vez, si regreso a Home, ya serían 2 veces, si vuelvo a Contacto, ya serían 3 veces que se acumula ese código y así.

Comment: Cito tu pregunta: "En mi pagina tengo diferentes secciones como Contacto, Perfil, etc, en las cuales llamo de igual forma a esta función.". Y repito, si el código comprueba constantemente el scroll, para qué lo llamas más de una vez?? No es una función que tengas que llamar varias veces ya que lo que estás haciendo es asignar una función para que se ejecute **CADA VEZ** que haces scroll: `$(window).on('scroll', function (){});` Si nunca remueves ese `$(window).on();` claro que se acumulan! Estás añadiendo más y más funciones al scroll en cada sección

Comment: Hola. Podrías intentar llamar tu código en un servicio y no en tu componente. Los servicios solo se instancian una vez a través de la inyección de dependencias.

Comment: @Benito-B si, pero no se supone que cuando cambio a otro componente, el anterior se "destruye" y por ende removerse ese ```$(window).on()``` . Puedo yo mismo adelantarme a la respuesta pensando que no se está removiendo, pero, xq en este caso no sucede, el evento no se agrega al componente si no a la página en si ???

Comment: @Legna si tambien lo tenía pensado hacer así cuando obtuve este error, pero me pareció interesante saber xq sucede esto y asi evitar este tipo de errores.

Comment: Si se destruye el componente, pero estas llamando a una constante global que no es destruida junto con el componente.

Comment: Si usas jQuery para añadir un handler a la `$(window).on('scroll');` da igual lo que hagas con tu componente, ese handler ahora está guardado en la ventana. Como te dice @Legna, sería mejor que ese tipo de cosas no las añadas desde un elemento si no desde un servicio que se instanciará solo una vez, porque es obvio viendo la consola que no se está removiendo el handler!

Comment: @Benito-B De hecho si utilizé un servicio para colocar mi función ahí y luego injectarla en mis componentes, y obtuve el mismo resultado, se seguia acumulando el handler. Opté por modificar mi función de javascript sin añadir el handler dejandolo así ```window.onscroll=()=>{...resto de código } ```